# Telnet to 1433 port not working for SQL Servers

Tags: sql-server

I have multiple SQL server databases running on multiple SQL Server of different versions and editions. I am trying to setup a monitoring server (say server X) from where I can monitor and make some automation. But when I am trying to telnet to my servers where SQL server is installed on port 1433 from server X then I am getting error. I can confirm that there are no firewall between the servers. Also, for few servers Network port scan shows destination server [A,B,C.....] is not listening on port 1433.

In some I can see remote system refused the connection.

I confirm that all my SQL Servers are using port 1433 and I am using that only to telnet.

I need to know what do I need to check to know where the problem is.

Comment: What is the problem actually ? You can't `telnet` to the server or you can't connect to `SQL server` via port `1433` ? Also please post the error message

Comment: When I'm using telnet to 1433 I am getting error. Telnet is just to check port 1433. If telnet is not happening how can SQL server get connected.

Comment: Connecting To XX.XXX.XXX.X...Could not open connection to the host, on port 1433

Comment: Firewalls, especially software-based firewalls, work in both directions... on the monitoring server you are testing from is telnet.exe allowed to make outbound connections?

Comment: yes, i am able to connect to some servers

Comment: Named instances eg. machinexyz\instance123 are not listening to port 1433, by default they use dynamic ports.

Comment: I am not having named instance

Answer (score 0):

Please follow this steps to port number 1433 on mssql server:

```
1. Start
2. All Programs
3. SQL server 2008
4. Configuration Tools
5. SQL server configuration manager
6. On the left side of new window SQL Server network configuration
7. Protocols for SQLEXPRESS
8. Double click on TPC/IP which is on left panel
9. On Protocol tab if Enabled is No Then Make Yes
10. Then click on IP Address tab
11. Scroll down and last IPALL, set TCP Port as 1433
12. Click Apply and then Ok button
```

**Reference:** https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VOUDdUJ5BLY